# Ruby on Rails + Cassandra on Netbeans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, cassandra

This equation works good?

Ruby on Rails + Cassandra on Netbeans6.9?

I have try installing the gem activerecord-cassandra-adapter, but the installation never works good.

Is there anybody using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start looking at the (three) Ruby high level libraries: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions